# Creating a function that reads off an input list of files

Tags: scripting, pipe, function, bioinformatics

I am in the process of writing bioinformatics pipelines. 
These pipelines take in input files and pass them through multiple packages.

Say there is a list of files that goes file1, file2, file3... file n, and for each I want to apply a function that goes  function1 -file 1| function 2 | function 3 > file 1.output but want to do it for the whole list of files using a for loop, and allocate file names to the output files accordingly, what commands and syntax should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information in your question, this should do what you requested:

```
for i in file1 file2 file3 file4 fileN
do
     function1 "$i"| function2 | function3 > "$i".output
done
```